# Running QT5 in an embedded device with 64 MB RAM

Tags: qt, embedded, qt5

I have been working with QML for a couple of weeks now. But now a new requirement has risen where I have to check whether I can run QT5 in an embedded device for my project. I need this for my GUI related operations. The device has an ARM processor (Intel ARM920T-PXA27x processor to be exact) with 64 MB RAM. 32 MB will be taken up for the OS and the rest will be available for application and QT.

I have to check whether this is possible. I have googled for some references and unable to find a suitable answer to my requirement with QT5. I need the GUI libraries but my project does not have advanced graphical requirements like swiping or animations. It contains basic controls like texts, buttons and lists/grids. Since I am new to QT especially to this part, I would like to hear whether

1) Is this a viable option and should I keep digging more into this? Any feedback would be welcome to know if it's worthy to spend time to attempt this or if it's a lost cause.

2) If there are options, could you point me in the right direction to look more into this?

Comment: QT5 means no QWS which means you "must" have a GPU: has your SoC it?

Comment: Yes, GPU is available in it

Comment: @LPs It's been possible to run Qt Quick 2 applications on hardware without OpenGL support since Qt 5.8 with Qt Quick 2D Renderer. Haven't tried it myself, though.

Comment: @talamaki Yes, probably, but on a single core CPU, what about performance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the OS you are running on your SOC.

It's definitely possible when running Linux. You can e.g. use [Qt Lite](http://blog.qt.io/blog/2017/05/31/qt-lite-qt-5-9-lts/) for configuring a minimal static build of Qt. Then you deploy your statically linked application to the device. You can check this [blog post](http://blog.basyskom.com/2017/qt-lite/) for experiences with Qt Lite.

One possibility is to go with [Qt for Device Creation](http://doc.qt.io/QtForDeviceCreation) for the whole embedded Linux based software stack which boots to a UI implemented with Qt technologies.

Comment: Thanks for the info. Could you provide me a ball park value of the memory that would be required while running a simple application(For eg. a 5 page application with basic controls like texts, buttons, lists, grids etc.). I have tried it in my Windows PC and a simple application uses about 16-18 MB of memory with QTQuick and controls.